# Multiple function definition in Jquery document.click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, domdocument

I have a javascript code like below :

---

```
function foo() {
    console.log("outer function")
}

$(document).click(function(event) {
    if(false) {
        foo();
        function foo() {
            console.log("inner function")
        }
    }
    else{
        foo();
    }
});
```

---

while invoking foo in else inside document.click it is throwing foo is not a function.

If I remove function definition from outside document.click then it works or if I remove function definition from inside document.click then also it works.

From the outcome I can sense some sort of scope issue. Since it is a scripting language it can take the latest definition and execute it but it is not doing it.

Can anyone please explain the background why it is shown as "foo is not a function", apologies if it is a silly question.

Comment: where is `{}` for function ? remove 2nd line

Comment: Sorry about the typo mistake Mahi, edited the snippet above

Comment: put `)` closing bracket after click event ends

Comment: foo is already defined don't try defining it again. `function foo()` twice?

Comment: Yeah zer00ne. But I need to know what is happening in the background which is throwing this error ?

Comment: Test1: First defined function removed Result1: Second defined function now works|||Test2: Second function removed Result2: First defined function works.|||Logic: Do no define a function more than once within the current scope.|||If it is entirely crucial that you must do this for some unfathomable reason, then create a namespace to avoid conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

```
        $(document).click(function(event) {
            function foo() {
                console.log("inner function")
            }
            if(true) {
                foo() //Here is my problem
            }
        })

        function foo() {
            console.log("outer function")
        }
```

when I running this code.There is no condition that [foo is not a function].
You can regard foo is a variable.when you invoke this function,the search algorithm is searching from the inner scope to the outer scope.

Comment: HI Liumy, Sorry for misleading my question, there was a mistake in my code that I have posted. I will repost it again with what I have